# Appending to an array in C

Tags: c, arrays

Let's say I have an array allocated in memory. How do I append directly to the end of the list? By this, I mean directly after the last entry already in the array.

My for loop (i=0;i<100;i++) is only adding elements to an array in certain cases, so it is not possible to append to the array using i.

My main question is: any way to append directly to the end of an array in C?

Thank you

Comment: You must reallocate the array using `realloc()` provided that the array was allocated using `malloc()`. That is the only way to get more space unless there's some unused space in the array.

Comment: There is unused space in the array. The array has already been allocated to the appropriate size. I just want to know how to append to it.

Comment: Then you need to track where the last thing is in the array and just put things after that. So for instance if your array is of size 100 and you've put 50 things in the array already you just do `arr[50] = new thing;` and for the next `arr[51] = next thing;` and so on.

Comment: @baba Then keep track of the last stored index and append next to it. Make sure you check everytime that you don't go beyond the list!

Comment: No other way to append besides tracking how many things have already been inserted into the array? I was looking for an alternative to that.

Comment: No. C gives you some basic tools, and you have to build upon that.

Comment: You need to store 2 or 3 things: the pointer to the array data, the active size of the array, and (optionally) the allocated capacity of the array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a comment, you said that there is unused space in the array, and that the array is already the appropriate size.  In that case, you just need a second variable to keep track of which element is "next".  Each time you "add" a value to the array, you just copy that value to the element at the index specified by the second variable, and then you just increment the second variable by one.

```
int i;
int index = 0;

for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    if (someCondition)
    {
        someArray[index++] = someValue;
    }
}
```

By saying `index++`, instead of `++index`, the value of `index` is not actually incremented until after `someValue` has been assigned to an element in the array.

```
int i;
int index = 0;

for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    if (i >= 90)
    {
        // if index == 0, for instance, someValue will be assigned to
        // someArray[0], and THEN index will be incremented to 1.
        someArray[index++] = someValue;
    }
}

// the first ten elements of someArray will be as follows:
//
// someArray[0] == 90
// someArray[1] == 91
// someArray[2] == 92
// someArray[3] == 93
// someArray[4] == 94
// someArray[5] == 95
// someArray[6] == 96
// someArray[7] == 97
// someArray[8] == 98
// someArray[9] == 99
```

Comment: Let's say I have 50 lists that I need to be appending to. Should I just create an array of size 50 that has all the index counters?

Comment: indexesArray = [index1, index2,...indexi...,index50]
and then increase indexi by 1 every time list i is appended to.

Comment: @baba That's probably a good idea.  You could set it up as having an array of arrays and an array of indeces.  Or you could do something a little more fancy with structs or something.

Answer (score 2):

No built-in function for appending an array in C (C++ & C# is a different story).
Just keep a pointer to your last inserted index in the array and move it forward until you reach the end of the array, that is a basic solution.